# How to write following equations in LaTeX format?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to add the two equations below in LaTeX, at the center of the page, without referencing.

I am a beginner and I need some expert help. (I need to add also the description text of m, n, x<sub>mn</sub>, and y<sub>mn</sub>)

[image]

Comment: Do you need to replicate the implicit abuse of notation exhibited in the first equation, in which `m` and `n` represent both summation indices *and* the numbers of rows and columns, respectively? Speaking for myself, I think it's better to avoid needless confusion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\mathit{MSE}=\frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (x_{ij}-y_{ij})^2 \\[2ex]
\begin{array}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} @{}}
m      & number of rows in cover image\\
n      & number of columns in cover image\\
x_{ij} & pixel value from cover image\\
y_{ij} & pixel value from stego image
\end{array} \\[2ex]
\mathit{PSNR}(x,y)=\frac{10\log_{10}[\max(\max(x),\max(y))]^2}{\abs{x-y}^2}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions. (a) To surround equations or groups of equations) with rectangular boxes, use the `\boxed` instruction. (b) To give an equation a caption, place it in a `figure` environment and use a `\caption` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\counterwithin{figure}{section} % optional
\usepackage[font={sf},skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{figure}{8}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\[
\boxed{%
\begin{gathered}
\mathit{MSE}=\frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (x_{ij}-y_{ij})^2 \\[1ex]
\begin{array}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} @{}}
m      & number of rows in cover image\\
n      & number of columns in cover image\\
x_{ij} & pixel value from cover image\\
y_{ij} & pixel value from stego image\\
\end{array} 
\end{gathered}
}% end of scope of \boxed
\]
\caption{MSE Algorithm}
\end{figure}

\[
\boxed{%
\mathit{PSNR}(x,y)=\frac{10\log_{10}[\max(\max(x),\max(y))]^2}{\abs{x-y}^2}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there any way draw a border around MSE and PSNR or PUt some Caption below the Equation ?

Comment: @uma - Please see the addendum I just below the initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

An answer:

```
\documentclass{article}‎‎
‎\usepackage{‎amsthm,‎amsmath‎‎}‎‎
\usepackage[utf8]{‎inputenc}‎
\begin{document}
‎‎
‎\begin{align*}‎‎‎
& ‎‎‎MSE = ‎‎‎‎\frac{1}{m n} ‎\sum‎_{m}‎\sum_{n} ‎(x_{mn}-y_{mn})^2 ‎\\‎
& m ‎‎‎\text{ ‎number of ...} ‎\\‎
‎& ‎n‎ ‎‎‎\text{‎ number of ...} ‎\\‎
& x_{‎mn}‎ ‎‎‎\text{ ‎pixel ‎value‎ ...} ‎\\‎
‎& ‎y‎_{‎mn}‎‎ ‎‎‎\text{‎ ixel ‎value‎‎ ...}‎‎‎‎
‎\end{align*}‎‎
\[‎
‎PSNR(‎x,y‎) ‎=‎\frac{10 \log_{10}(\max(\max(‎x‎)‎,\max(y)‎)^2}{‎|x-y|^2‎}‎‎
\]‎

\end{document}
```

A closed parenthesis is lost in the second one!

Comment: The command `\rm` has been deprecated for 25 years.

Comment: You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ‎ (U+200E)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. it is given like this error

Comment: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ‎ (U+200E) same error given me, when i added this refferenc to , %title =        {ImageHash \-  Easy Steganography},
  %howpublished = {\url{https://medium.com/@elisklar/imagehash-easy-steganography-240b92b586e2}},

Comment: I added this to Preamble '\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{}' and then remove that error. is it ok?

Comment: I think one should definitely not try to replicate the `m\ast n` (or `m^\ast n`) "feature" in the screenshot. If it's essential to use an explicit multiplication symbol, one might write `m\cdot n`.